# How to parse nested structures from string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, tree

I have a string structured like this

```
id i { 
    any data; any [con=tent] 
    id j { 
         any inner data 
    }
    id k {
         bla 
         id m {
             any
         }
    thing }
}
```

Where the `id NAME { CONTENT }` is a pattern of nestable objects. The desired target would look like:

```
public class Node {
    public List<Node> InnerNodes;
    public string Contents; 
    public string Name; 
}
```

How to parse such objects tree with C#.Net using opensource packages?

Comment: Use a recursive algorithm.

Comment: Write a parser.... on the second thought, why do you use this? Use JSON or YAML. And parsers for them already written and available

Comment: The grammar here is more than just `id NAME { CONTENT }`. You need to provide the full details of how to parse this data.

Comment: @Enigmativity: that is the main point - split it into string of NAME and nested CONTENT

Comment: @DuckQueen - But the grammar is clearly more than `id NAME { CONTENT }`, and to say "split it into string of NAME and nested CONTENT" is actually even less descriptive. You need to provide the proper grammar for us to parse this.

Comment: @DuckQueen - An excellent way to describe it would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form#Example.

Comment: @DuckQueen - I can clearly see that where there is an `id` there is a `NAME` and `{` followed by `CONTENT` and then a `}`, but the `CONTENT` contains other `id`s and **also other stuff** like `"any data; any [con=tent]"`, `"bla"`, and `"thing"`. Your class shows you want a nested structure, but your grammar doesn't explain how to parse the **other stuff** to extract out the nested nodes. You need to provide the correct grammar.

Comment: @Enigmativity: there is no need in parsing of other stuff - only raw nested structure (and inner content as strings

Comment: @DuckQueen - "only raw nested structure" - that's the problem. It's not "raw" - it contains some `id NAME { CONTENT }` and some other stuff. It all requires parsing. You can't just parse some and not parse the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the most performant way to solve this issue, nor the cleaner, nor the most comprehensive... but probably the shorter.

This uses regex stacks (only avaible with .Net regex engine, i think). [A good tutorial about those, applied to nested constructions matching here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21080/In-Depth-with-RegEx-Matching-Nested-Constructions)

```
void Main()
{
    var input = @"id i { 
        any data; any [con=tent] 
        id j { 
            any inner data 
        }
        id k {
            bla 
            id m {
                any
            }
        thing }
    }";
    Process(input).Dump();
}

public class Node {
    public List<Node> InnerNodes;
    public string Contents; 
    public string Name; 
}

Regex reg = new Regex(@"
    id\s+(?<name>\w+)\s*\{(?<body>(?<DEPTH>)
        (?>(?<DEPTH>)\{ | \}(?<-DEPTH>) | (?(DEPTH)[^\{\}]* | ) )*
        )\}(?<-DEPTH>)(?(DEPTH)(?!))
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled);

List<Node> Process(string body){
    return reg.Matches(body)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x=>new Node{
            Name=x.Groups["name"].Value,
            Contents=x.Groups["body"].Value.Trim(),
            InnerNodes=Process(x.Groups["body"].Value),
        }).ToList();
}
```

Which outputs

[image: output]

(nb: the `.Dump()` is the Linqpad extension that just dumps the generated object)

Answer (score 3):

@T.S. pointed out in the comments there’s, apart from educational purposes, rarely a good reason to reinvent the wheel. When it comes to writing parsers, it’s those corner cases which make it hard to get right:

- validation of the format, more specifically returning friendly
  messages to the user
- optimising your code for performance, allocations, concurrency,…

That said, with C# 7’s support for pattern matching, the basic plumbing should be easy enough to implement.

First stop, the `Node` class, adding initialisation.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        InnerNodes = new List<Node>();
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    public List<Node> InnerNodes { get; }
}
```

Next, creating wrappers for the distinct parts of our grammar.

```
internal abstract class Token
{
}

internal class OpenNodeToken : Token
{
    public OpenNodeToken(string name) { Name = name; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

internal class CloseNodeToken : Token
{
}

internal class ContentToken : Token
{
    public ContentToken(string text) { Text = text; }
    public string Text { get; }
}
```

And a helper class to transform our input string into a sequence of tokens.

```
internal static class Tokenizer
{
    public static IEnumerable<Token> Scan (string expression)
    {
        var words = new Queue<string>
            (expression.Split(new[] { ' ', '\n', '\r', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        while (words.Any())
        {
            string word = words.Dequeue();
            switch (word)
            {
                case "id":
                    yield return new OpenNodeToken(words.Dequeue());
                    words.Dequeue();
                    break;

                case "}":
                    yield return new CloseNodeToken();
                    break;

                default:
                    yield return new ContentToken(word);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used a `Queue` in order to dequeue multiple strings in one go for the `id` case.

Finally, the parser, where pattern matching allows for succinct code.

```
public static class Parser
{
    private static Node currNode;
    private static Stack<Node> prevNodes;
    private static IEnumerable<Token> tokens;

    static Parser()
    {
        prevNodes = new Stack<Node>();
    }

    public static Node Deserialize(string input)
    {
        tokens = Tokenizer.Scan(input);
        if (!(tokens.FirstOrDefault() is OpenNodeToken rootToken)) 
            throw new FormatException("Missing root node");
        currNode = new Node(rootToken.Name);

        foreach(Token token in tokens.Skip(1))
        {
    switch (token)          
            {
                case ContentToken c:
                    string s = string.IsNullOrEmpty(currNode.Contents) ? c.Text : " " + c.Text;
                    currNode.Contents += s;
                    break;

                case OpenNodeToken n:
                    prevNodes.Push(currNode);
                    currNode = new Node(n.Name);
                    break;

                case CloseNodeToken c:
                    if (prevNodes.Any())
                    {
                        Node childNode = currNode; 
                        currNode = prevNodes.Pop();
                        currNode.InnerNodes.Add(childNode);
                    }
                    break;

                default: throw new NotImplementedException(token.GetType().Name);
            }
        }
        return currNode;
    }
}
```

Here we use a `Stack` to push parent nodes onto before parsing a child. Once the child’s closing bracket is met, we pop the parent of the stack and add the child to its collection.

As mentioned, a decent parser should also cover the corner cases, I’ve left the joys of implementing those to the reader. To test the parser I’ve set up the console project below.

```
namespace MySimpleParser
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = GetInput();
            try
            {
                Node root = Parser.Deserialize(s);
                PrintBranch(root, 1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        internal static string GetInput()
        {
            return @"id i { 
                        any data; any [con=tent]
                        id j {
                            any inner data
                        }
                        id k {
                            bla
                            id m {
                                any
                            }
                            thing 
                        }
                    }";
        }

        internal static void PrintNode(Node n, int depth)
        {
            string indent = new string('-', 3 * depth);
            Console.WriteLine($"{indent} Name: {n.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{indent} Contents: {n.Contents}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{indent} Child Nodes: {n.InnerNodes.Count}");
        }

        internal static void PrintBranch(Node root, int depth)
        {
            PrintNode(root, depth);
            foreach (Node child in root.InnerNodes) PrintBranch(child, depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
--- Name: i
--- Contents: any data; any [con=tent]
--- Child Nodes: 2
------ Name: j
------ Contents: any inner data
------ Child Nodes: 0
------ Name: k
------ Contents: bla thing
------ Child Nodes: 1
--------- Name: m
--------- Contents: any
--------- Child Nodes: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems similar to another text book problem of checking if Paranthesis are balanced. Basically take a stack, parse the string, when you encounter opening brackets... understand that an Object is being created. and the Closing bracket helps mark the object as complete.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple options:

1. Learn to write, and write, a parser for the document type. There are a good number of online resources like [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/dashboard) that will help you do this. If you want to take this route, I'd suggest looking at the strings section, as many of them help teach this sort of operation. While this is by far the most difficult path, you'll wind up better for having learned it.
2. Use a library. There are a number of different parser libraries out there for C#, each with their own pros and cons. My personal favorite at the moment is [SuperPower](https://github.com/datalust/superpower), which seems to be the simplest monadic parser library to just pick up and use without having to know a whole lot about functional programming or parsing in general.

If I knew a little bit more about the situation, I'd be able to give better guidance, but the information you've given is pretty thin. Information that would be useful:

- Size/Speed requirements.
- A more exact definition of the document structure.