# Parsing data from nested brackets in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, text-parsing

Finally solved this myself after making many styles of parsers suffering from the same bug...
Working (cleaner but still needs more cleaning) code [Here](https://github.com/geromet/EU4Editor/tree/master/EU4Importer)

if(input > 47 & input < 123) should be
if(input > 44 & input < 123) to include the '.'
thanks for no help.

Modifying [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826768/16545202) example code almost works for me, and is a starting point to learn more.

I've been trying to parse some files from the game Europa Universalis IV.
The files contain text like this:

[Example 1](https://github.com/geromet/EU4Editor/blob/master/EU4Importer/Source/common/religions/00_religion.txt)

[Example 2](https://github.com/geromet/EU4Editor/blob/master/EU4Importer/Source/common/ideas/00_country_ideas.txt)

In case someone wants to help debug [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dPayDM) is a browser version with 2 processed OuterEntities as example.

Once everything works the data would be put into a database after every object is finished. For testing I just write my progress to a text file.

I have tried this a couple times in different ways that almost always end up looking the same. By now the process is split into parts, and most of them work.

I start by collecting all the "OuterEntities" (First level brackets) in each of the GameFiles (just one for fast testing), this step is easy.
I put those outer entities into a list in a GameFile object (ToString overrides are just for testing) :

**GameFile**

```
 internal record GameFile
{
    public List<string> UnprocessedOuterEntites = new();
    public string Name;
    public string Path;
    public List<OuterEntity> OuterEntities = new();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new();
        sb.AppendLine(Name);
        sb.AppendLine(Path);
        foreach(OuterEntity entity in OuterEntities)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(entity.ToString());
        }
        foreach(string entity in UnprocessedOuterEntites)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(entity);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

**OuterEntity**

```
internal class OuterEntity
{
    public List<string> UnprocessedInnerEntities = new();
    public string? Name = "";
    public List<InnerEntity> InnerEntities = new();
    public void Clear()
    {
        this.UnprocessedInnerEntities.Clear();
        this.InnerEntities.Clear();
        this.Name = null;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new();
        sb.Append(Name);
        foreach (InnerEntity entity in InnerEntities)
        {
            sb.Append(entity.ToString());
        }
        foreach(string entity in UnprocessedInnerEntities)
        {
            sb.Append(entity);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Those OuterEntities contain InnerEntities, which contain values or more InnerEntities (Nested brackets) :

**Inner Entity**

```
internal class InnerEntity
{
    public List<string> UnprocessedInnerEntities = new();
    public string? Name;
    public string? Value;
    public List<InnerEntity> InnerEntities = new();
    public void Clear()
    {
        this.Name = null;
        this.Value = null;
        this.InnerEntities = new();
        this.UnprocessedInnerEntities = new();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(Name);
        if (InnerEntities.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (InnerEntity entity in InnerEntities)
            {
                sb.Append(entity.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendLine(Value);
        }
        foreach (string String in UnprocessedInnerEntities)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(String);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

**The program is (for testing) run like this:**

```
internal class Program{
private static Program program = new();
public List<GameFile> gameFiles = new();
public static void Main()
{
    program.Run();
}
private void Run()
{
    string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles("Source", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        Process.GetOuterEntities(path,this);
    }
    Process.ProcessOuterEntities(this);
    Process.ProcessInnerEntities(this);
    Test.PrintOuterEntities(this);
}}
```

**The OuterEntities are collected and processed:**

```
public static void GetOuterEntities(string path, Program program)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
        GameFile file = new GameFile() { Path = path };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int currentPos = 0;
        int lastPos = 0;
        int brackets = 0;
        bool inBrackets = false;
        string st = RemoveComments(lines);
        OuterEntity entity = new OuterEntity();
        foreach (char c in st)
        {
            if (c == '{')
            {
                inBrackets = true;
                brackets++;
            }
            else if (c == '}')
            {
                brackets--;
            }
            if (brackets == 0 && inBrackets)//End Outer
            {
                sb.Clear();
                inBrackets = false;
                for (int i = lastPos; i <= currentPos; i++)
                {
                    if (st[i] != '\n')
                    {
                        sb.Append(st[i]);
                    }
                }
                file.UnprocessedOuterEntites.Add(sb.ToString());
                program.gameFiles.Add(file);
                lastPos = currentPos + 1;
            }
            currentPos++;
        }

 public static void ProcessOuterEntities(Program program)
    {
        foreach (GameFile file in program.gameFiles)
        {
            foreach (string UnprocessedOuterEntity in file.UnprocessedOuterEntites)
            {
                file.OuterEntities.Add(ProcessOuterEntity(UnprocessedOuterEntity));
            }
            file.UnprocessedOuterEntites.Clear();
        }
    }


private static OuterEntity ProcessOuterEntity(string UnprocessedOuterEntity)
    {
        OuterEntity processedOuterEntity = new();
        int currentPos = 0;
        int lastPos = 0;
        int brackets = 0;
        bool inBrackets = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in UnprocessedOuterEntity)
        {
            if (c == '{')
            {
                if (processedOuterEntity.Name == "")
                {
                    for (int i = lastPos; i <= currentPos; i++)
                    {
                        if (UnprocessedOuterEntity[i] != '\n')
                        {
                            sb.Append(UnprocessedOuterEntity[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    processedOuterEntity.Name = sb.ToString();
                    sb.Clear();
                    lastPos = currentPos + 1;
                }
                inBrackets = true;
                brackets++;
            }
            else if (c == '}')
            {
                brackets--;
            }
            if (brackets == 0 && inBrackets)
            {
                inBrackets = false;
                for (int i = lastPos; i <= currentPos; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(UnprocessedOuterEntity[i]);
                }
                processedOuterEntity.UnprocessedInnerEntities.Add(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
                lastPos = currentPos + 1;
            }
            currentPos++;
        }
        return processedOuterEntity;
    }
```

After this I fail to process the inner entities.

**This is the currently not working part:**

```
 private static InnerEntity ProcessInnerEntity(string UnprocessedInnerEntity, bool WaitingForValue = false)
    {
        InnerEntity processedInnerEntity = new();
        int currentPos = 0;
        int lastPos = 0;
        int brackets = 0;
        bool inBrackets = false;
        bool waitingForValue = WaitingForValue;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in UnprocessedInnerEntity)
        {
           
            if (c == '{')//Brackets opening
            {
                inBrackets = true;
                brackets++;
            }
            else if (c == '}')//Brackets closing
            {
                brackets--;
            }
            else if (c == '=')//Name behind, Value or NestedEntity in front
            {
                for (int i = lastPos; i <= currentPos; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(UnprocessedInnerEntity[i]);
                }
                processedInnerEntity.Name = sb.ToString();
                sb.Clear();
                lastPos = currentPos + 1;
                waitingForValue = true;
                if (inBrackets)//In a nested bracket, find InnerEntity
                {
                    processedInnerEntity.InnerEntities.Add(ProcessInnerEntity(UnprocessedInnerEntity.Substring(currentPos + 1), waitingForValue));//Search everything in front
                }
            }
            else if (c<47 | c > 123)//Not text
            {
                if (waitingForValue)//After =
                {
                    for (int i = lastPos; i <= currentPos; i++)
                    {
                        if (c > 47 & c < 123)//Text
                        {
                            waitingForValue = false;
                            sb.Append(UnprocessedInnerEntity[i]); 
                        }
                    }
                    if (!waitingForValue)//Has value
                    {
                        processedInnerEntity.Value = sb.ToString();
                        sb.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (brackets == 0 && inBrackets)//Brackets closed
            {
                inBrackets = false;
                currentPos++;
                break;
            }
            currentPos++;
        }
        return processedInnerEntity;
    }
```

The rest of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/geromet/EU4Editor/tree/master/EU4Importer)

**The debug file is written like this**

```
 internal class Test
{
    public static void PrintOuterEntities(Program program)
    {
        List<string> strings = new();
        foreach (GameFile gameFile in program.gameFiles)
        {
            strings.Add(gameFile.ToString());
        }
        foreach (string String in strings)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("test.txt", String);
        }
    }
}
```

**Current output looks like this:**

```
source\common\ideas\00_country_ideas.txt
HLR_ideas = { 1     diplomatic_reputation =
 2  }       bonus =

 2  }       bonus =


GER_ideas = { 0.3       infantry_power =
 0.15   }       bonus =

 0.15   }       bonus =

 0.15   }       bonus =

 0.15   }       bonus =
```

I want a list of OuterEntities containing their InnerEntities like this:

```
OuterEntity //Object
Name HLR_Ideas
InnerEntities //List
    Name start
        InnerEntities 
            Name possible_policy
                Value 1
            Name diplomatic_reputation
                Value 2
    Name bonus
        InnerEntities
            Name administrative_efficiency
                Value 0.05
    Name trigger
        InnerEntities
            Name tag
                Value HLR
    Name free
        Value yes
    Name hlr_imperial_throne
        InnerEntities
            Name legitimacy
                Value 1.5
    Name hlr_kaiserliche_armee
        InnerEntities
            Name land_morale
                Value 0.15
    Name hlr_imperial_diplomacy
        InnerEntities
            Name improve_relation_modifier
                Value 0.33
    Name hlr_centralised_empire
        InnerEntities
            Name global_tax_modifier 
                Value 0.2
    Name hlr_roman_heritage 
        InnerEntities
            Name core_creation 
                Value -0.2
    Name hlr_adopting_the_goosestep 
        InnerEntities
            Name discipline
                Value 0.05
    Name hlr_onwards_and_upwards 
        InnerEntities
            Name governing_capacity_modifier 
                Value 0.1
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong in the last part? Are there existing wheels I don't know about I'm trying to reinvent? Do I just learn Perl or the fancy non regular regular expressions I see out there?

Comment: You ae parsing json text which is as regular as you think.  Which text file is failing?

Comment: This is not json text right? Have you looked at the example files? I am failing to recursively get the data from the nested brackets. All the reading I've done points to the conclusion that this is not regular, and the few (complicated) "regular" expressions are actually unregular.

Comment: It looks like json.  You never said it issue was due to recursion.  You never said what errors you are getting.  Recursion is not easy to debug.  Normally I recommend for recursion creating an output file and put debug information into the debug file.

Comment: I am not sure the issue is recursion. Might be something else I'm not seeing. In the current state, I am not getting any errors, just wEIrD ReSUltS. I've added an example of the wanted output. I'll also add the code where I create the output file with debug information for clarity.

Comment: As I said, best way of debugging recursion is to open a file and put message in file to help isolate issue.  I've done this thousand of times in 45 years.

Comment: this is definitely not JSON. It's JSON-like, but not JSON.

Comment: @jdweng I agree with my 22 years of living. This way I've fixed the stuff around it. Now I'm very sure the issue is in the InnerEntity ProcessInnerEntity. Might be some basic logic I'm doing wrong while checking the chars. I've had issues with recursion going deeper than it actually is (bad code) but those are fixed. I'm hoping someone just points me to some C# grammar thing I can use to fix this whole problem in a few lines.

Comment: We are not going to run your code for you.  I'm am 3 times your age and have a vast more experience than you.  You have to isolate why the code is occurring and with which text it is failing.  DO NOT MAKE ASSUMPTIONS.

Comment: You can't learn if you do not try.  I usually help much more than other people at this site.  I help when I feel a person cannot easily solve the issue themselves.  I do not help when a person is just lazy and does not want to do the work them selves.

Comment: I have done the work a couple times now. If you personally don't want to help that's fine. And I guess your explanation will help me write better questions.

Comment: I'll back up @jdweng 's point.  The way to fix this problem is to isolate the issue and find a test case that fails.   This example is to big for us to help with -- you need what is called a minimal reproducible problem.  That is showing us the problem with the least code possible.  Often just making such an example solves the problem -- there is the rare time when you find a bug outside your code -- but it is not often.

Comment: I'd also put forward that this code is fundamentally not the best way to solve this problem.  Parsing regular syntax is easiest done with a recursive descent parser.  I think this would be well served to try that -- you are going to have less bugs.  There is the reason it is the standard way.  If the syntax is not regular then you will need LLR or some such.  Plenty of classes, books, articles explain all this.

Comment: @Hogan Thank you for those new research topics :) I know this is fundamentally wrong, but I'm having trouble finding the way. "Recursive descent parser" and "LLR" are new terms for me :) I also added a pretty minimal online test to my question. Doing this DID ACTUALLY make me see problems (for future, not current) again. I'll try finding some books though.

Comment: @Hogan Have I not reinvented a wheel by making a recursive descent parser already? if (inBrackets) //In a nested bracket, find InnerEntity
     {
      processedInnerEntity.InnerEntities.Add(ProcessInnerEntity(UnprocessedInnerEntity.Substring(currentPos + 1),waitingForValue)); //Search everything in front
     }

Comment: https://github.com/b3b00/csly/wiki/getting-started Looking into this now :)

Comment: Yes your design is very similar to a RDP but by splitting it into classes it makes it fundamentally not.  Ideally you want a parser class that does the parsing and the other objects would be token and scanner.

Comment: There are a lot of tools that make parsers and lexers -- remember to understand the difference -- the lexer performs actions on based on parsed elements and the parser actually parses the code.  (This is how you build a compiler)

Comment: Here is a good article to get you started -- and it uses the token class as I mentioned http://blog.roboblob.com/2014/12/12/introduction-to-recursive-descent-parsers-with-csharp/

Comment: Typically, the best way to handle this kind of thing is to understand what kind of text you are parsing. There are very few truly unique different formats. Typically you're working with some for known format like YAML, JSON, XML, CSV, etc. What you want to do is find out exactly what kind of format this is, and then **USE AN EXISTING GENERIC PARSER THAT UNDERSTANDS THAT FORMAT!!** Again, what you have is none of these, but it's _something_. Or if it's not, it _could be_ if you go back to the original source and ask for it that way.

Comment: @Hogan thanks for the explanation. I had found those articles already, but they make more sense after modifying the parser I linked at the top of my post. Now I have other problems and ideas to fix those. Need to sleep first though.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That would be my preferred solution. Haven't had any luck finding anything though. The rules are pretty simple. Original source would be Paradox Development Studio. I doubt they would respond to me asking for their parser. Game source is also closed. We just have access to the data files.

Comment: It's doubtful Paradox Dev Studio made up their own format from scratch. They're also using something more generic. Find out what it is.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Okay. I'll try looking harder. It's 00:08 for me though so it's gotta wait.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn This was unexpected. I found someone who made a parser for the wiki (not what I need), messaged him, did more research, and now I've found something that seems to take care of everything, and even makes future problems easier.  Thanks for the suggestion. https://github.com/nickbabcock/Pdoxcl2Sharp#style-of-file